# Error when dumping Database from PGAdmin?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm trying to dump a database i created on pgadmin, because i need a .sql file to send to my Professor for a University project.

Whenever i try to do a Backup, it instantly stops because of this command:

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin/pg_dump --file "/Users/fstxfreestyler/CinemaDB" --host "localhost" 
--port "5433" --username "postgres" --no-password 
--verbose --format=p --create --clean --inserts 
--column-inserts --encoding "UTF8" "cinema"
```

I'm using pgadming 4.28, on a MacOS 10.13.3.

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by *because of this command*? Which errors do you get?

Comment: It literally says 'backing up an object on the server "Cinema(localhost:5433) from database 'cinema'..., running command:" and then the command i posted. Nothing else.

Comment: Upgrade pgAdmin4 to something less broken than 4.28.  That version ate error messages instead of displaying them.  Better yet, just run the pg_dump command directly.